# I want to know how to perform input and output operations in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I want to know how to perform input and output operations in C#. I know C++ but I want to write a code in C#. This is the basic code in C++. I want to write the same thing using C# language.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char name;
    cout<<"\n Enter name";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Hello!!"<<name<<": \t ";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You cannot store a name, which is most likely a string, into a single `char` (`char name;`). Use `std::string name;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.ReadLine`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Clear()

    string name;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name: ");

    name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Hello! {0}:\t", name);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: It is not actually equivalent to C++ code. And I do not mean few spaces here and there. I mean absence of `Console.Clear()` at the beginning and `Console.ReadLine()` in place of `Console.ReadKey()`.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Yes. it is not exactly equivalent to C++. As the title of this question reflect the main concern of it's writer, I concentrated on two method: `WriteLine` and `ReadLine` and showed how `string.Format` like syntaxes are working in c#

Comment: It is my own opinion, so I do not force you to do so, but I think that when one decides to answer LMGTFY questions, (s)he should strive to do it with as high level of quality as possible - with solid explanations, references to documentation and best practices.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Thanks for participating making a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

To output your result to the Console then you can use
`Console` class and use it's function like

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Clear();
    char name;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
    name=Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!!"+name+": \t ");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

if you want to redirect the output to file or other options you need to check for [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) or other `Stream` Classes